# Iterate faster over a large collection of files (objects) inside an Observable List (JavaFX 8)

Tags: javafx, lambda, collections, stream, filepath

I have an excel file that contains all the filenames of the Images. The path of these images are stored in an `Observable Collection` via `<File>` class which came from the folder that contains all of the images. My goal is to create a hyperlink of these filenames by matching it through the pool of image file collection.

I would like to ask if how can I iterate faster through a large collection of file classes in order to get their paths easily.

For example:

Image name from Excel :

`ABC_0001`

The Full path from the collection must be:

```
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Images\ABC_0001.jpg
```

In order to get their full path, I perform the iteration through Stream.

My procedures:

1. Extract data using Apache POI.
2. Stream through the Image Collection by converting each data into
   their base filenames vs extracted data.
3. Get the result and store the fullpath on the object via
   `getAbsolutePath()`.

Code:

```
//storage during iteration
ObservableList<DetailedData> dataCollection = FXCollections.observableArrayList()

//Image collection containing over 13k Images listed via commons-io
ObservableList<File> IMAGE_COLLECTION =  FXCollections.observableArrayList(FileUtils.listFiles(browsedFOLDER, new String[]{"JPG", "JPEG", "TIF", "TIFF", "jpg", "jpeg", "tif", "tiff"}, true));

//Sheet data
Sheet sheet1 = wb.getsheetAt(0);

 for (Row row: sheet1)
 {
    DetailedData data = new DetailedData();

    //extracted data from excel
    String FILENAME = row.getCell(0,Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK).getStringCellValue();

    //to be filled up based on stream result.
    String IMAGE_SOURCE = null;

    //stream code with the help of commons-io
    File IMAGE = IMAGE_COLLECTION.stream().filter(e -> FilenameUtils.getBaseName(e.getName()).toLowerCase().equals(FILENAME.toLowerCase())).findFirst().orElse(null);

    if (IMAGE != null)
      IMAGE_SOURCE = IMAGE.getAbsolutePath();


    data.setFileName(FILENAME);
    data.setFullPath(IMAGE_SOURCE);
    dataCollection.add(data);

   }
```

Result:

```
Excel rows = 9,400
Image Files = 13,000

Iteration Time = 120,000ms
```

Are the results should appear normal or it can become faster?

I tried using `parallelStream()` and the results went faster but it consumes higher CPU usage.

Comment: profile to find the exact bottleneck - more often than not, it's not where we expect it to be :)

Comment: Just looking at your code, what you are doing seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should speed your code up a lot, but there are a few questions about your code.

1. `ObservableList<DetailedData> dataCollection = FXCollections.observableArrayList()` Why are you using `ObservableList`? Why is this a list of `DetailedData` and not `File`. Given that detailed data has `setFileName` and `setFullPath`. File already has these.
2. `ObservableList<File> IMAGE_COLLECTION =  FXCollections.observableArrayList(FileUtils.listFiles(browsedFOLDER, new String[]{"JPG", "JPEG", "TIF", "TIFF", "jpg", "jpeg", "tif", "tiff"}, true));` Why `ObservableList`?

These two are small things, but I am curious.

So what I think you should do is use a `Map`. Your code should look something like the code below.

```
//storage during iteration
List<DetailedData> dataCollection = new ArrayList();

//Image collection containing over 13k Images listed via commons-io
List<File> IMAGE_COLLECTION =  new ArrayList(FileUtils.listFiles(new File("C:\\Users\\blj0011\\Pictures"), new String[]{"JPG", "JPEG", "TIF", "TIFF", "jpg", "jpeg", "tif", "tiff"}, true));

//Use this to map file name to file  
Map<String, File> map = new HashMap();

//Use this to add data to the map
IMAGE_COLLECTION.forEach((file) -> {map.put(file.getName().substring(0, file.getName().lastIndexOf(".")).toLowerCase(), file);});

for (Row row: sheet1)
{
   //extracted data from excel
    String FILENAME = row.getCell(0,Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK).getStringCellValue();

    //If the map contains the file name, create `DetailedData` object. Then set data. Then add object to datacollection list.
    if (map.containsKey(FILENAME.toLowerCase()))
    {
        DetailedData data = new DetailedData();
        data.setFileName(FILENAME);
        data.setFullPath(map.get(FILENAME.toLowerCase()).getAbsolutePath());
        dataCollection.add(data);
    }
}
```

**Comments in the code**

I still believe this could be cleaned up a little more if you used `List<File> dataCollection = new ArrayList()`

Comment: Maybe I can add that you still do the FILENAME.toLowerCase() conversion twice. Otherwise there isn't much left to be done for the OP :-)

Comment: That's true. I should have used `equalIgnoreCase` on the one. I will update the code.

Comment: @mipa after looking over the code again, I think it's needed in this case. this is assuming that the file name and the Excel file name content may not have the same case. I assume this is the case based on the OP's code.

Comment: Why! If you add a 'final String lowerCaseFileName = FILENAME.toLowerCase()' before the if-statement you can use this in the if-statement and in its body as the map-key. So, the conversion has to be done only once.

Comment: Oh yea. I actually didn't notice that case inside the if-statement. I also believe had the user left out `DetailedDate` and used `File` in his list that this would be no problem. It would have been `dataCollection.add(file)` only in the if-statement.

Comment: I really thank you guys for helping me solving this problem. I am using ObservableCollection to bind its size to my UI Label so that the users know how many records and images were loaded by the program. 

For now this was the best coding style for iterating that I have read so far. I'm not a good at using Maps but I now believe this is worth studying!

Comment: If this answer help you achieve your goal, you should accept it as correct. @Kagetsuchi.

Comment: Also, I am curious to know how fast did this speed up your code?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to speed up your search, you should try not to do things repeatedly which could just be done once. For example you could use two loops. The first to prepare your search and the second to actually do the search. Inside your filter you call FilenameUtils.getBaseName and two time a conversion to lower case. It would be better to do these things only once in the first loop and store the resulting Strings in a list. In the second loop you then do the search on this list.

I am also wondering why you use ObservableLists here. A simple List would do as well.

Comment: thanks for this! I frequently use ObservableCollection as my data containers without knowing the reason why. Does a List consume less memory?

Comment: Yes, observability comes at a price.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested another approach in this slow iteration.

It seems that the cause is declaring the `Stream` repeatedly inside the `foreach`.

I tried using Baeldung's [solution](https://www.baeldung.com/java-stream-operated-upon-or-closed-exception) `<Supplier>` and declared it outside the loop together with `parallelStream()`

Sample Code:

```
Supplier<Stream<File>> streamSupplier = () -> imageCollection.parallelStream();

for (Row row : sheet) 
 {

      File IMAGE = streamSupplier.get().filter(e -> FilenameUtils.getBaseName(e.getName()).toLowerCase().equals(FILENAME.toLowerCase())).findFirst().orElse(null);

      if (IMAGE != null)
      IMAGE_SOURCE = IMAGE.getAbsolutePath();

 }
```

Result went `45000ms`

Please correct me if my approach was not right.

Comment: The "Baeldungs's solution" has nothing to do with your problem. You are still doing the same thing as before just hidden inside some lambda.